# "result of string concatenation is too long"

Tags: oracle, listagg

I have a query which uses listagg it is as follows

```
SELECT listagg(path1.PATHWAY_ID,'|like||id|')within GROUP (
ORDER BY path1.PATHWAY_ID),
  listagg(path1.PATHWAY_NAME,'|like||name|') within GROUP (
ORDER BY path1.PATHWAY_ID)
FROM CI_PUBLIC.GG_PATHWAY path1,
  ci_public.gg_pathway_folder_tree path2
WHERE path1.PATHWAY_ID=path2.DESCENDANT_ID
AND path2.ANCESTOR_TREE_CODE='**VALUE TO BE PASSED**'
AND path2.ANCESTOR_DEPTH=path2.DESCENDANT_DEPTH-1;
```

The number of results the query should return is 131 but I get below error

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.
```

But when I pass a different value to path2.ANCESTOR_TREE_CODE it retrieves results.
There is nothing wrong with the query the only problem is when it has more results it gives error.

Is there anyway that I can get more results using listagg?

Comment: No, there is no way around that. You will need to do the aggregation in your application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long